# vNext Application_Start() equivalent

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make this call one time during startup.

```
var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

This was brought over from a MVC 4 project.

Calling it from Startup.ConfigureServices or Startup.Configure throws an exception;

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.

1. Where in the vNext startup pipeline can I start making calls similar to this that do not conflict with pre-start initialization.
2. Separate question, should I be making this explicit call BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(); during startup.  Reason for the call is to find all Assemblies for this app, find all areas in the app, find all controllers in the app, and impose filters on all of them.  In the past I imposed Auth filters on every controller and did not rely on developers to put [Authorize] attributes on actions.  It put a stop to surprise security holes showing up. Developers had to opt out via configuration from having this done to them, and that introduced a documented security audit trail.

I have researched the Middleware stuff but I like to do all my hookups up front and then let the app framework work as it likes.

Someone else suggested using OWIN, but I would like to follow vNext conventions if all possible and not do any mix and matching.

Another suggestion was putting Global.asax back in, etc.

Thanks for any direction that would be consistent to the vNext way.

Comment: Putting the code in Application_Start in Global.asax might serve your purpose.

Comment: BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies() is not relevant to asp.net-core. Nor is Glabal.asax. Startup.cs is the entry point. I'm not sure how to list all assemblies.

Comment: If you're looking for ways to stay in core and do it, take a look at this thread on the github site for coreclr, it looks like it's got a few leads to get you in the right direction (assuming all of this hasn't changed, it is 7 months old and every release has upended everything thus far):  https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/919

Comment: The middleware "stuff" is exactly what you should do.

Comment: There's an alternate way to apply filters using ApplicationModel: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/WebSites/ApplicationModelWebSite/Startup.cs
In your case, you could add a `IControllerModelConvention` that adds the filters you need. Alternatively, why not apply a global filter?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen on the ApplicationStarted event. Try this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime lifetime) {
    lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => {
        // Your code goes here
    });
}
```